# Creating stock.picking from another model - Odoo v8

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo-8, odoo

I have this method:

```
@api.multi
def create_printy(self):
    copy_record = self.env['stock.picking'] # now you call the method directly
    for record in self:

        order_lines = []
        for rec in record.order_lines:
            order_lines.append(
            (0,0,
            {
                'product_id': rec.isbn.id,
                'product_qty': rec.qty,
                }
            ))
        copy_record.create({
            'origin': order.name,
            'picking_type_id.id': 'outgoing',
            'move_lines': order_lines, 
            'move_type': 'direct',
            'priority': '1',
            'company_id': record.company_id.id,
        })
```

This is a button which should create a new `stock.picking` from my model.

I've tried with `picking_type_id.id` but it seems to not work, on every example in the standard addons, You just see `picking_type_id`, also, I don't have any defined in my model, but I though I could pass one of the types available, which is `outgoing` (the one I need).

Right now, it throws me this:

```
Integrity Error

The operation cannot be completed, probably due to the following:
- deletion: you may be trying to delete a record while other records still reference it
- creation/update: a mandatory field is not correctly set

[object with reference: picking_type_id - picking.type.id]
```

So, how can I pass this `picking_type_id` into the `stock.picking`, should I define this field in my model, even if not required? But it is required by `stock.picking` model though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The field `picking_type_id` is mandatory in `stock.picking` model, and you are not specifying it in the `create` method, instead, you are specifying a value for `picking_type_id.id`, which is not a field (and Odoo is not leting you know this fact). You must find the ID of a stock picking type object, and pass it to the `create` method. As you want an outgoing type, look for picking types with this code. If you have several warehouses the search method is bound to return several records, that's why I am getting the first one. But if you want another one, you will have to pass more parameters to the `search` method to be more concise. So try this:

```
@api.multi
def create_printy(self):
    copy_record = self.env['stock.picking'] # now you call the method directly
    for record in self:
        order_lines = []
        for rec in record.order_lines:
            order_lines.append(
            (0,0,
            {
                'product_id': rec.isbn.id,
                'product_qty': rec.qty,
                }
            ))

        sp_types = self.env['stock.picking.type'].search([
            ('code', '=', 'outgoing')
        ])
        if len(sp_types) > 0:
            copy_record.create({
                'origin': order.name,
                'picking_type_id': sp_types[0].id,
                'move_lines': order_lines, 
                'move_type': 'direct',
                'priority': '1',
                'company_id': record.company_id.id,
            })
```

Comment: Kick ass, Thank You very much! I have some other doubt, but I'll open a new question for that, cheers.